# How to subtract the mean of past calendar weeks from the current value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a dataframe df_pct_Max with the following shape:

```
    Date    Value1  Value2
01.01.2015   5        6
08.01.2015   3        2
...          ...      ...
28.01.2017   7        8
```

and I would like to calculate the average per calendar week and subtract it from the actual values for the calendar week.

I have created a dataframe with the average per calendar week as follows:

```
df_weekly_avg_Max = df_pct_Max.groupby(df_pct_Max.index.week).mean()
```

This results in a dataframe df_weekly_avg_Max:

```
    KW  Value1  Value2
      1   3.5   4.3
      2    4    3
      …    …    …
     52    8.33  6.2
```

Now I am trying substract df_weekly_avg_Max from df_pct_Max and would like to do this by calendar week.

I have tried adding a column 'KW' and then

```
dfresult = df_pct_Max.sub(df_weekly_avg_Max, axis='KW')
```

But I am getting erros there.

Is there also a way of doing this on a rolling basis (suntracting the average of calendar week 1 over the past 3 years from calendar week 1 of 2015 and the 2016...)?
Could someone please help with this issue?

Comment: Is every day in every week in your `df_pct_Max`? Can you provide more lines in both of your dataframes?

Comment: Not every day of the week is part of the dataframe. It has one day in each week as timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for the whole dataframe.
I added a column 'KW' for the calendar week and then performed a groupby on it with a lambda function that subtracts the mean for the calendar weeks "1" from the current value of calendar week "1"...

```
df_pct_Max ['KW']     = df_pct_Max.index.week
dfresult = df_pct_Max.groupby(by='KW').transform(lambda x: x-x.mean())
```

This works for me.

It would have been nicer to be able to adjust the timeframe of the mean, e.g. I substract from the current calendar week "1" value the mean for calendar week one of the past 3 years or so. But this seems rather complicated and this solution works for the current analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't clean as it doesn't make use of pandas well, but I also don't think it will be slow (depends on how large your dataframe is), the basic idea is to build up a list of the means repeated once for each day so you can subtract simply.

CODE:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Build up example data frame
num_days = 15
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=num_days, freq='D')
val1s = np.random.random_integers(1, 30, num_days)
val2s = np.random.random_integers(1, 30, num_days)

df_pct_MAX = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates, 'Value1':val1s, 'Value2':val2s})
df_pct_MAX['Day'] = df_pct_MAX['Date'].dt.weekday_name
df_pct_MAX['Week'] = df_pct_MAX['Date'].dt.week

#OPs logic to get means
df_weekly_avg_Max = df_pct_MAX.groupby(df_pct_MAX['Week']).mean()

#Build up a list of the means repeated once for each day in that week
mean_fields = ['Value1','Value2'] #<-- only hardcoded portion
means_dict = {k:list(df_weekly_avg_Max[k]) for k in mean_fields} #<-- convert means into lists keyed by field
week_counts = Counter(df_pct_MAX['Week']).values() #<-- count how many days are represented in each week

#Build up a dict keyed by field with the means repeated the correct number of times
means = {k:[means_dict[k][i] for i,count in enumerate(week_counts)
         for x in range(count)] for k in mean_fields}

#Assign a new column to the means for each field (not necessary, just to show done correctly)
for k in mean_fields:
    df_pct_MAX[k+'Mean'] = means[k]

print(df_pct_MAX)
```

OUTPUT:

```
         Date  Value1  Value2        Day  Week  Value1Mean  Value2Mean
0  2015-01-01      12      19   Thursday     1    9.000000   19.250000
1  2015-01-02      15      27     Friday     1    9.000000   19.250000
2  2015-01-03       2      30   Saturday     1    9.000000   19.250000
3  2015-01-04       7       1     Sunday     1    9.000000   19.250000
4  2015-01-05       6      20     Monday     2   17.571429   14.142857
5  2015-01-06       9      24    Tuesday     2   17.571429   14.142857
6  2015-01-07      25      17  Wednesday     2   17.571429   14.142857
7  2015-01-08      22       8   Thursday     2   17.571429   14.142857
8  2015-01-09      30       7     Friday     2   17.571429   14.142857
9  2015-01-10      10       1   Saturday     2   17.571429   14.142857
10 2015-01-11      21      22     Sunday     2   17.571429   14.142857
11 2015-01-12      23      29     Monday     3   23.750000   19.750000
12 2015-01-13      23      16    Tuesday     3   23.750000   19.750000
13 2015-01-14      21      17  Wednesday     3   23.750000   19.750000
14 2015-01-15      28      17   Thursday     3   23.750000   19.750000
```